# Google Apps Script: getPlainBody() weird behavior

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a Google App Script to parse and extract some content of some emails from Gmail. Unfortunately, I am having a quite hard time parsing the content of a message.

I am calling `getPlainBody()` on a `GmailMessage` to apply some parsing via a regex, however it doesn't seem to work properly. It looks like that the string returned by `getPlainBody()` is incomplete. Let me explain better.

When I apply the regex in this way it doesn't find anything.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  // code to get messages from GmailApp

  const body = message.getPlainBody()
  const result = body.match(/word/gm) // nothing found

  const templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('messages');
  templ.body = body
  
  return templ.evaluate();
}
```

If I visit the Google Script App rendered by the code above, I copy the string value of `body` rendered via the template, I open the console on the Dev tools and I apply the exact same regex to the copied string, it's working.

Am I missing something? It looks like that the value of `body` is not "ready" when I try to access it with the `match` function.

Comment: If you look at the emails that you are having trouble with with the show original option near the upper right corner of the email in gmail does your email have sections that have been ascii encoded.  That may be the problem.

Comment: Have you investigated the log of `body` between `const body` and `const result`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of debugging, I finally found the culprit: **the** **debugger**. The function `getPlainBody()` is working perfectly, it's the Google Script App debugger that is cleaning up the string returned by the function when showing it in the debug panel.

My `body` variable was full of `\r` and `\n` characters that were not showing on the debugging session. This explains why the regex was working fine
when tested on [regex101](https://regex101.com/): the string I was copying from the debugger wasn't the actual string assigned to `body`.

I have spotted the error when I have tried to `console.log(body)` and then noticed that the value was completely different from the one shown in the debugger.

I fixed the code with the following line:

```js
const body = message.getPlainBody().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. When I wanted to display the body of an email in the console, the complete body content was never displayed.
I solved the problem using the `getRawContent()` function, then my regex worked without any problems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).